# How to develop config file editors like EntLib have?

Tags: enterprise-library

All.

How to develop config file editors like EntLib have?
Is there the library that I can reuse in the EntLib Framework?

Or may be EntLib reuse third party library?

Is it possible extend EntLib console with my own custom sections editors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Enterprise Library configuration tool is a custom WPF application.

If you want to develop a similar application, I would recommend downloading the source code for inspiration or as a base for developing your app.

Comment: Yes, it's a custom-build WPF application. You are welcomed to reuse it.

Comment: I have checked sources. After first look I can't estimate how much time I need for inspiration trance over the source code... I will spent more time but if somebdoy could provide quick information what should be moved to the "custom config file sections editor" it would be good.